# How to Loop through an Array of User Controls and gain access to the controls in it

Tags: arrays, vb.net, user-controls

I need to loop through an array of user controls that were programmatically created.
Where My problem is later I need to loop through the array of user controls created and use the controls of the user control
My sudo code.   The line I cannot figure out is

> MyCtrl.tbQtyM.Text = Format(60 / Val(MyCtrl.tbMPU.Text) / 55 * NumEmployees, "0.00")

```
Dim MyProds As New MyMPUProduct
For iLoop2 = 1 To Val(sender.Text)
    MyProds = New MyMPUProduct
    Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(MyProds)
    With MyProds
        .Name = "MyProd" & iLoop2
        .Location = New Point(6, MyProdSpace)
        .VerifyTMPUProductsTblApt()
        .TMPUProductsBindingSource.Filter = "ID = '-1'"
        .tbMix.Text = "0"
        .Label1.Text = iLoop2
    End With
Next
Dim CtrlName As String
For i = 1 To NumProds
    CtrlName = "MyProd" & i
    For Each MyCtrl As Control In Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls
        If TypeOf MyCtrl Is MyMPUProduct Then
            MyCtrl.tbQtyM.Text = Format(60 / Val(MyCtrl.tbMPU.Text) / 55 * NumEmployees, "0.00")
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: What's the issue though?

Comment: Typically when you create a UserControl you do so to *encapsulate* certain functionality including managing the child controls so that other form / class code does need to. You could have a method where the form/class passes some data and the UC does whatever to the child controls.  Also is *pseudo*; `sudo` is slang for an ingredient in meth.

Comment: The Issue Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC30456 'tbQtyM' is not a member of 'Control'. JWMT C:\Users\johndavi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JWMT\JWMT\frmMPUGoals.vb 577 Active